# Create a branch in a repo without cloning

Tags: git, github

I am doing some grading for a intro web class and we are using GitHub to host their files. Unfortunately for me we forgot to tell the students about `gh-pages` to so that they could view their code online (everyone was just viewing locally). I do not want to clone all their repos onto my computer nor do I want to add the branch manually online. Does anyone know a terminal command to create a branch on a remote repository if you do not have the repo? (I am a owner of all of their repos). What I want to do is just write a script that will run this command on all the the student repos and create the `gh-pages` branch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you'll write a script in any case, so what's the problem? Pseudocode:

```
for repo in repos
    git clone repo .
    git branch gh-pages
    git push origin gh-pages
    rm -rf .
```

Comment: What was not said explicitly in this answer is that no, @trev9065, you cannot change anything about a remote repo if you don't have a clone of it.

Comment: besides, trying to change the repos that **doesn't** belong to you is deprecated.

Comment: Yeah mostly I wanted to avoid this because of the time out would take, but it sounds like this may be the only option.

Answer (score 0):

you can't, github doesn't provide feature for creating branch online.

Comment: You can create branches online, by clicking the branch and typing in a new branch to search for it you can create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this script:

- https://gitlab.apertis.org/em/git-pushref/-/blob/main/git-pushref